# how to apply CSS-transition depending on sibling div in TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, css-transitions

when i click on "item.title", "item.text" will open. this works well. but the transition that i applied on "item.text" doesn't work when it will open. so when i click on "item.title", the "item.title" should open with this transition.

```
  return (
    <div
      className="flex-col border-b-2 border-slate-100"
    >
      <div
        onClick={handleSetIsOpen}
        className="px-5 pt-3 pb-2 font-bold cursor-pointer"
      >
        {item.title}
      </div>
      <div
        className={`px-3 pb-3 ${
          isOpen ? "opacity-100 max-h-screen transition duration-500 ease-in-out" : "hidden opacity-0 max-h-0 transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out"
        }`}
      >
        {item.text}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

i passed the transition to the parent div but the "item.title" will give this transition too. but i don't want this. this transition should only work on "item.title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CSS transitions happen on the same frame as when `display: none` is applied or removed. Thus, consider removing the `hidden` class altogether:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  const handleSetIsOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen(value => !value);
  };
  
  const item = {
    title: 'Foo',
    text: 'bar',
  };
  
  return (
    <div
      className="flex-col border-b-2 border-slate-100"
    >
      <div
        onClick={handleSetIsOpen}
        className="px-5 pt-3 pb-2 font-bold cursor-pointer"
      >
        {item.title}
      </div>
      <div
        className={`px-3 pb-3 ${
          isOpen ? "opacity-100 max-h-screen transition duration-500 ease-in-out" : "opacity-0 max-h-0 transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out"
        }`}
      >
        {item.text}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```